# Extending System.Xml.Linq.XElement - internal CloneNode

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, .net-4.5, xelement

I have class `Foo` extending `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, but when I call

`Foo parent = ..;
Foo child = ..;
parent.Add(child);`

added child is not of type `Foo`, it is of type `XElement`.

This is because of `internal abstract XNode CloneNode()` which is called inside `Add` method.

I can't override this because of internal. What are my options in this case? I wouldn't like to override each function calling `CloneNode()`.

Comment: What is the code you are trying to add using the subclass `Foo` ? Since it appears that you can't access or modify the creation process may be it is possible to extend the `XElement` using another technique.

Comment: I am adding some extra meta-data for each node, it would be good to keep Xml.Linq functionality to navigate, search and other operations on this structure. I guess ill have to make wrapper to do this, but this requires much more code than extending XElement. Because extra members are needed i can't use Extension methods.

Comment: More a workaround... What about using your class `Foo` as long as possible and convert it to an `XElement` as required? And the conversion adds all your extra information.

Comment: The subclassing approach seems to require subclassing the whole namespace, then you could of course modify the creation process. But maybe someone else has got something better to contribute.

Comment: I would like to use Foo all the time, but problem is that i can't because as soon as I start to work on node (check example in question), object are converted to base class.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have one ugly solution, more like temporary hack than solution, not working generally, just to patch current code. I am not sure that there is any nice solution, other than to rewrite code without extending XElement, so I will post this.

CloneNode is called in Add only when parent field is not null, but Parent property has only get, and parent field is internal. So easiest way to fix my problem is to hide XElement Add with this in XElementExtended:

```
static FieldInfo parentProperty = typeof(XElementExtended).GetField("parent",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
public void Add(XElementExtended element)
{
    var el = new XElementExtended(element);
    parentProperty.SetValue(el, null);
    base.Add(el);
}
```

Comment: I guest that i could try to fix this better by playing with reflection and emiting override of CloneNode, but this is more complicated, and I am not sure if it will work as expected. Even if could make fix more consistent, it is still ugly ;(

Answer (score 0):

XElement as an entity is part of the XML model itself. You would extend it if you were adding some functionality to XML like a new kind of Node. And even then, the XNode implementation is still correct because it knows absolutely nothing about your new XML. As far as I know XML isn't extensible it self, e.g you can't add a new kind of node.

If you're trying to Typify your XML data then the correct approach will be to build your data model separately and implement read/write methods on the root entities.

If you want to tag your elements then you'll have to either build a wrapper around the whole model straight from XDocument or index the information on the side with `Dictionary<XElement, something>`.